# Memory copy not getting created during forking

Tags: c++, fork

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594329/difference-between-the-address-space-of-parent-process-and-its-child-process-in) link and copy-on-write concept, When we fork the child process and the parent process point to the same memory initially, until one of the process modifies the memory. It will then create a copy of that memory and modification will be done to that memory. But according to the output of the below code, parent and child are pointing to the memory, even after it is modified by the child process. Is there a reasoning to it?

```
using namespace std;
using ULL = unsigned long long;
int gFlag = 0;

int main ()
{
        gFlag = 1;
        cout << (ULL)&gFlag << endl;

        pid_t ret = fork ();

        if (ret > 0) {

                sleep (6);

                cout << "Parent: " << gFlag << endl;
                cout << "Parent: " << (ULL)&gFlag << endl;

                return 0;
        } else {

                gFlag = 15;
                cout << "Child: " << gFlag << endl;
                cout << "Child: " << (ULL)&gFlag << endl;
        }

 

        return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
94022699245908
Child: 15
Child: 94022699245908
Parent: 1
Parent: 94022699245908
```

Comment: Those are virtual addresses, not physical. Each process can map them differently to the physical memory. (And C++ doesn't allow objects to change their address when modified or otherwise, it doesn't know anything about the `fork` copy-on-write thing.)

Comment: You don't see a difference because you print the address of the virtual memory address, not the physical address in memory. It gets copied in the memory and the MMU changes the mapping from virtual to physical memory for the child process. So, all pointers in your program are still valid.

Comment: Think about how your way would work and `gFlag` _would_ receive a new address when forking .. how would your OS identify all the places where `gFlag` is referenced by address (eg pointers on the stack, in registers, squirreled away in an on-heap structure, ...)?

Comment: Side note: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) – and aliasing `unsigned long long` just for the sake of shorter names is actually information hiding (every one knows the original name, the abbreviation might need to be looked up), so don't recommend either – in given case even worse as the alias is the same as the `ULL` suffix for unsigned long long integer literals.

Comment: The accepted answer in the link you posted in the question ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594329/difference-between-the-address-space-of-parent-process-and-its-child-process-in)), actually explains that the child process gets its own separate virtual address space, which is initially a duplicate of the parent's.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is just how `fork()` works on many operating systems.